# Como usar um kit de UI (PSD) em um aplicativo Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá! Recentemente me deparei com diversos kits de UI para Android feitos no Photoshop (PSD). Como eu faço para utilizá-los em minha aplicação? Por exemplo, eu tenho esse kit: http://medialoot.com/images/uploads/sketch-full.jpg

Não consigo achar uma maneira de usá-los no meu projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Você deveria exportar todas as imagens em um formato que o Android aceite (PNG, JPEG, etc.)
Depois, é só ajustar as medidas e outras propriedades dos componentes de interface padrões.

Comment: Existe uma maneira de ajustar as medidas automaticamente?